# Checkbox, radio button and Lightning input outlines not visible in production but showing in Sandbox in Experience cloud

Tags: lightning-web-components, community-cloud, experience-cloud

I have a search page that I have deployed to production in experience cloud but the lightning input is not showing the box outline, the checkboxes are not visible as well as the radio button. I have used LWCs for the implementation. The checkboxes and lightning input can be clicked but the outlines are not visible.

Production output [image: Production]

sandbox output [image: sandbox]

How can I resolve this? Thanks!

Comment: what makes you think this is a configuration issue? are the elements disabled? or is this just a styling issue?

Comment: kindly check the FLS for the fields mentioned in the LWC.

Comment: I was just suspecting. What exactly about styling do you suggest could cause this? The same stylesheets are working in sandbox.

Comment: @glls I think you might be right. I deployed again and after previewing I am able to click but the outlines are still not visible. I however still don't know how to resolve the styling to make the outlines visible.

Comment: you will have to inspect the elements (using your browsers debugging tools) to see if there is any difference between the two

Comment: Thanks. Let me explore that.

Comment: @glls, I did as you asked and identified that the difference was in a file app.js. I have created a new question for this.

Comment: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/346217/app-css-is-causing-difference-in-appearance-between-sandbox-and-production-in-ex

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to use overrides since the app.css file with the different styling is part of the lightning framework.

In experience builder I went to theme -> theme settings -> edit css and added the styles that were affected eg. for the lighting input I added..

```
.slds-input{
     border: 1px solid rgb(25, 71, 141);
}
```