# App.css is causing difference in appearance between sandbox and Production in Experience cloud. How do I find it to update it?

Tags: css, experience-cloud

I have a page in communities that I deployed but the appearance differed such that the outlines for the checkbox and textboxes were not visible. After comparing the styling in devtools, I identified that the difference was in a file called app.css that I did not create myself.

After modifying the file in devtools, the pages output match. I therefore want to update the app.css in production to solve the issue. How can I do that given that I did not create the app.css file myself?

The different outputs are shown the images below
[image: production]
[image]

For the app.css sample code..
Production
[image]

In sandbox..
[image: sandbox]

I am wondering whether this stylesheet comes out of the box from Salesforce.

Comment: Are you using any custom design token to style? I would also check if there is anything different in Global CSS for experience in both environment + If the theme colors/branding sets are same or not. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.communities_dev.meta/communities_dev/communities_dev_customize_css.htm and https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=community_builder_theme_adjust.htm&type=0

Comment: No. No design tokens. I don't even know how to use those. I have compared the theme settings and matched to look alike but that did not solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have probably different release on Sandbox and on Production. You can check when release for your instance is on [Salesforce Status](https://status.salesforce.com/)
Salesforce changed a lot in styling in last release therefore you can observe differences and yes file you've mentioned is connected to standard Salesforce styling (SLDS which can be checked [here](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/))

Furthermore you can override styles of Salesforce provided components (which is not recommended because there is a chance it won't fit in nicely in next releases).
Documentation around that is [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.communities_dev.meta/communities_dev/communities_dev_customize_css.htm)

Obviously you can also change look and feel via Experience (Community) Builder which should not break anything in the future.

Going further: in Summer 21 Salesforce finally released Styling Hooks which can be used with your custom LWC components. It means that your custom components can be (minimally though) styled via Builder now which is mentioned [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_experiences_lwr_branding.htm&type=5&release=232)

Comment: The override turned out to be the solution. Thanks!